# What is the diffrence between std::greater{} and std::greater<int>()?

Tags: c++, stl

Some people write

```
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+1, v.end(), std::greater{});
```

and some write like this

```
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin()+1, v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

What is thre diffrence between `std::greater{}` and `std::greater<int>()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is new as of C++14, and this results in two completely different classes.

In C++14, `std::greater` acquires a default value for its template parameter: `void`.

You end up with either `std::greater<void>` or `std::greater<int>`.

`std::greater<void>` is a specialization for a [so-called "transparent" comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_void) that deduces its parameters, see its reference for more information.

Answer (score 4):

`std::greater<int>` has an `bool operator()(int const&,int const&) const` that calls `>`.

`std::greater<>`, aka `std::greater<void>`, has a template references `auto operator()(T const&, U const&) const` that calls `>` and deduces its return value.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and earlier, `greater<void>` and `<>` won't work.

In practice there will be no difference here.  Under any non zero optimization, both versions of the comparison will be inlined.

In other contexts, the `void` version will let you compare dissimilar types (with suitable `<` or conversion overloads), and lets you neglect the type you are comparing.

The other big detail is that `<void>` advertises a `is_transparent` tag.  When passed to a container like `std::map`, it changes some of the methods to have template arguments.  This permits using a `std::string` key without forcing the lookup strings to become the same object type, which can save copies and allocations.